# Como actualizar la informacion de un DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, donde su fuente es un DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, datagridview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que la información en la columna ComboBox "**Código de articulo**" del **dataGridView2**, se actualice si modifico el código de algún artículo del **dataGridView1** en la columna "Código de articulo".

Con mi código actual, cuando modifico el código de un artículo en el **dataGridView1**, en el dataGridView2 en la columna ComboBox "**Código de articulo**", no se modifica el código, lo que sucede es que se agregan un nuevo código con el nuevo valor.
Este es el código:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int seleccionFila;

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        seleccionFila = e.RowIndex;
        InsertarCodigoComboBox();
    }

    private void InsertarCodigoComboBox()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(0))
        {
            string codigo = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;

            if (codigo != null)
            {
                if (CodigoComboBox.Items.Contains(codigo) == false)
                {
                    CodigoComboBox.Items.Add(codigo);
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu metodo está claro que lo que haces es agregar un nuevo código y no seleccionarlo, como parece ser lo que deseas. Te agrego el código con comentarios explicativos.

```
    private void InsertarCodigoComboBox()
    {
        //Obtenemos el valor del código de la fila activa en el dataGridView1
        string codigo = (string)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        if (codigo != null)
        {
           //Verificamos si no existe el codigo
           if (CodigoComboBox.Items.Contains(codigo) == false)
           {
             //Esta linea lo que hace es agregar el nuevo codigo a los items del ComboBox, si no existe.
             CodigoComboBox.Items.Add(codigo);
           }
         //Ahora asignamos el valor a la celda de la fila activa del dataGridView2
         dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[CodigoComboBox.Index].Value = codigo;
       }
 }
```

Comment: gracias por la atencion, en la ultima linea: 
(CodigoComboBox[dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index].Value = codigo;)
El visualStudio arroja el siguiente error:
"Error CS0021 No se puede aplicar la indización con [] a una expresión del tipo 'DataGridViewComboBoxColumn' DataGridViewComboBox"

Comment: Prueba a poner codigocombobox.items[...]...

Comment: @Ariel Tienes razón no se puede acceder a las celdas del `DataGridView` directamente desde el objeto `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, he editado la pregunta con la corrección, accediendo a la celda correspondiente a partir del objeto `dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells`. Pruebalo y me dices si te funcionó.

Comment: Si funciono, solo me queda construirle a parte un metodo para hacerlo con mas de una fila. Gracias

Comment: @Ariel Bueno ese es el camino, estamos aquí para ayudarnos, cualquier otra duda planteas una nueva pregunta y seguro alguno de los usuarios te responderá.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con este código, espero te sea de ayuda:

```
 DataTable dt;
    private void FrmFormulario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTable();
    }

private void AddTable()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("codArticulo");
        dt.Columns.Add("DescripcionArticulo");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

private void GetCodigos()
    {
        try
        {
            //Aceptamos los cambios en caso de que se hallan eliminado filas
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView2.Columns["codArt"];
            Col.DataSource = dt.Copy();
            Col.DisplayMember = "codArticulo";
            Col.ValueMember = "codArticulo";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Obteniendo Codigo...");
        }
    }

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "codArt")
            {
                GetCodigos();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: La respuesta que brindas, se aleja demasiado del problema planteado en la pregunta; para responder bien, deberias centrarte en el problema planteado por el preguntante, nunca debe asumirse que una solución, por mucho que te parezca que le será util, es la solución para el problema que está planteando, si no responde con exactitud y precisión a lo que esta preguntando.

Comment: Considero que el problema que él menciona es que se le duplica el registro en el combo al querer editar algún registro de la grilla; simplemente le ofrezco una manera de poder sortear tal problema y a como yo lo haría.

Comment: Pero en el texto de su pregunta ni en el código que el coloca, se evidencia el enlace a datos que asumes y que colocas en tu código, nunca se ha hecho referencia a enlace a base de datos en el texto de la pregunta ni en le codigo que colocó el preguntante, en ese aspecto te sales del ambito del problema que está planteando la pregunta. Puede que tu solución enlazada a datos sea mejor, pero no es lo que plantea la pregunta.

Comment: Si interpretaras o visualizaras mejor el código que brindé, te dieras cuenta que en ningún momento hago alguna consulta a base de datos, sólo que al declarar el datatable y asignarlo al datagirdviwe1 evito que recorra el mismo.